# Posting content as a user using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post content as a user using facebook graph api but I am not able to do so.

As per documentation,
[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#publishing)

```
Publishing

You can only publish to a Page and only with a Page access token of a Page if you can perform the CREATE task on the Page.
```

Also [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/#Updating)

```
Updating

You can publish posts by using the /{user-id}/feed, /{page-id}/feed, /{event-id}/feed, or /{group-id}/feed edges.
```

According to above docs, I'm using *POST v7.0/{user-id}/feed* to post data with body as '*message=hello*'.

But in response I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AFMLDOB0UJOGejUhnOUSgtN"
  }
}
```

So my question is, can I post only in a group or page and not as a individual user?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting to a user feed is not possible anymore, the required permission `publich_actions` has been removed a while ago.

Comment: Is there any alternative for the same??

Comment: there is no direct api for it, but you can use the share dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/ - prefilling the message would not be allowed anyway, so you would have to let the user enter it anyway.